# `range` option not working properly in `\setmathfont`

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts

I want to use *XITS Math* font for numbers and *Latin Modern Math* by default. But

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={`0-`9}]

\begin{document}
1234567890
$ x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}, \xi\alpha\beta, 1234567890 $
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

A magic number `"0391` helps to generate the intended output

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={`0-`9,"0391}]

\begin{document}
1234567890
$ x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}, \xi\alpha\beta, 1234567890 $
\end{document}
```

[image]

All effective numbers are `"0391-"03A1,"03A3-"03AF,"03B1-"03BF,"03F4,"2202,"2207,"1D434-"1D454,"1D456-"1D467,"1D6E2-"1D6FA,"1D6FC-"1D714`.

Why are these numbers so special?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for this is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={up/num,
                               bfup/num},
                        Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
1234567890
$ x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}, \xi\alpha\beta, 1234567890 $
\end{document}
```

You can look up the meaning of those Unicode codepoints in [the symbol list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).  It doesn’t look as if the package is correctly parsing the expression `` `0-`9 `` on its own, but it does understand slight variations.

Comment: But `"0030-"0039` behaves the same as ```0-`9``. So can unicode-math handle `⟨unicode range⟩` at all, as it said in the document?

Comment: @TuffContender Yes, I’ve used that syntax in my documents before. It doesn’t seem to recognize math digits specifically without `up/`.